# What does `grep -E "xyz\.(.+)\.abc"` do in korn shell?

Tags: regex, shell, grep, ksh

I have seen this piece of code in a ksh script. Wondering what it does?

```
grep -E "xyz\.(.+)\.abc"
```

Comment: what's unclear about that and what have you tried? Did you try to run `grep --help` and read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Korn shell. [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is a tool for matching [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and the `-E` option specifies that extended regex should be used instead of the default basic regex. For more information about that read [Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) or run `man grep`, `man regex`

So `grep -E "xyz\.(.+)\.abc"` will find a line containing the string `xyz.` followed by anything then `.abc` in the input. Since there's no input file specified, it'll read the input from stdin